# How to set up push to some device with Parse push notification?

Tags: parsing, notifications, push

I try to push to 2 device among 4 device, by set conditional to push is device name. add 2 conditional with device name is "LamLT's iphone" and "iPad mini 3". but parse only send push to 1 device. i don't know why. Please help me resolve it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Did you set property for Device Name to array ?